# How do I make my own question as community?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I know that how to make my own answer as community wiki. How do I make my own question as community wiki?

Comment: **You cannot.** Community-wiki questions are only manually set by diamond moderators under rare circumstances. CW questions are usually famous important questions with a very high degree of activity.

Answer (score 7):

> How do I make my own question as community wiki?

From this post https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741

Since **October 2010**, there is no community wiki checkbox when asking a question

check this answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67582

> We removed that option globally from all questions.
>
> If it really needs to be wiki, flag it for moderator attention, it was causing confusion and pain.